# How to use `graphql` with flutter?

Tags: flutter, nestjs

I'm new to `flutter` and used `nestjs` with `graphql` for the backend, and for the front end like to use `flutter`.
could you recommend any package that uses `graphql` with `flutter`?

Comment: Packages are [graphql_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/graphql_flutter),  [flutter_graphql](https://pub.dev/packages/graphql_flutter) and more....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer to this medium article by FlutterDevs: https://medium.flutterdevs.com/graphql-flutter-603d57c05656

This is the link to the repository for the example of using GraphQL with Flutter:
https://github.com/flutter-devs/Flutter-GraphQLDemo

And this is the official link of pub dev:
https://pub.dev/packages/graphql_flutter